# Class with '__getitem__' has no 'get' method

Tags: python, python-datamodel

I realize that naturally a class with no `get` method has no `get` method. What would be the best way to add a `get` method to a class implementing `__getitem__` [without boilerplate]?

I tried:

```
class Foo():
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        ...

    get = dict.get  # TypeError
```

But python complains:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'get' for 'dict' objects doesn't apply to 'Foo' object
```

Clearly as `collections.UserDict` could be used, but I was hoping to be lazy (because the resolution is expensive) and not populate the item data until its accessed (and cached by key on the `Foo` object).

Thoughts?

Comment: *Write* the method?

Comment: You mention wanting your code to be lazy and avoiding expensive work, but it's not clear really how you can be lazy about implementing `get` for a dictionary-like class. What exactly is the work you'd hope to skip?

Comment: It also seems like you might want to use the mixin methods of the `collections.abc.Mapping` abstract base class. If you use it as the base class for your own type, you only need to implement `__getitem__`, `__len__` and `__iter__` and it will give you all the rest of the (read-only) mapping API. If you want to be mutable, then inherit from `MutableMapping` instead, and add `__setitem__` and `__delitem__`.

Comment: Since your class isn't a `dict` (or a subclass of one), you'll need to `def get(self, <args...>):` and define what it means/does.

Answer (score 0):

Not that the get method is overly complex, I was hoping python had builtins to reduce this kind of boilerplate...

```
class Foo():
    ...
    def get(self, item, default):
        try:
            return self[item]
        except KeyError as err:
            return default
```

Comment: @Sanyash: Looks like an answer to me. Question: how do you give this class this method? Answer: write the method.

Comment: @Sanyash I would agree but mods tend to agreesively freeze useful posts, so I like to have an answer when posting just so there is _soemthing_ for future googler's to get out of this post.

Comment: Incidentally, `IndexError` is the exception for sequences. `KeyError` is the one for mappings. `get` methods are more usual for mappings than for sequences, so it's a bit weird that your `__getitem__` seems to raise `IndexError`.

Comment: If you move content of this answer to your question, future googlers will still get this content from your post.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks, caught in testing and not before posted q_q

Comment: 1.  If you're also interested in `IndexError`, the sibling of `KeyError`, then the "parent" exception is `LookupError`.  2. consider defaulting `default` to `None`.